# Double 'evaluate' in one PGF's \foreach

Tags: tikz-pgf

percusse may know if I can do the following with `\foreach`:

```
\begin{document}
\foreach [
  evaluate=\x as \z using \x*10,
  evaluate=\x as \p using \x mm*3
] \x in {1,...,5}{
  \endgraf
  \hskip\p pt\relax
  \textcolor{red!\z!blue}{\x}%
}
\end{document}
```

**Aside**

`\foreach` should help newbie with an intelligent message in a case like the following:

```
\foreach [
  remember=\x % as \lastx (initially A) % n00b forgot the rest.
] \x in {B,C,D,E,F,G,H}{%
  $\overrightarrow{\lastx\x}$,
}
```

Comment: Just came here searching how to use multiple evaluate !

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The `evaluate` keyword invokes the PGF math engine, which always saves its results in units of `pt`, but without the `pt` string. So if you use

```
\hskip\p pt\relax
```

(adding the `pt` after the `\p`), you get the desired result:

[image]

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\foreach [
  evaluate=\x as \z using \x*20,
  evaluate=\x as \p using \x mm*3
] \x in {1,...,5}{
  \endgraf
  \hskip\p pt\relax
  \textcolor{red!\z!blue}{\x}%
}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks. Then I just do `evaluate=\x as \p using \x*3` with `\hskip\p mm\relax`.

Comment: @AhmedMusa Thanks for the direct reference. We have a very knowledgable bunch here including yourself so I'm kinda embarrassed :0).

Comment: @AhmedMusa You want "x times 3mm", so use `\x*3mm` and `\hskip\p pt\relax`. Later, you can change `3mm` to `1em` or `\baselineskip` without any change in your `\hskip...` command.

Comment: @percusse: Every tikZ expert is called percusse, like every TeX user was called Ben User by Knuth. I chose percusse over Andrew Stacey, Jake, Tom Bombadil, etc., because percusse sounds like a word.

Comment: @PaulGaborit: That makes some sense. Thanks.